# Actionbar.removealltabs() leaving behind the tabs space

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs, android-actionbar

Actionbar.removealltabs removes all my tabs. However, the remaining space used to hold the tabs are still there. As a result my actionbar looks like a very tall actionbar with a empty bottom half.

Using support actionbar with appcompatactivity.

I've tried calling Actionbar.removealltabs in both my fragment and Mainactivity... same result.

[Tabs pre-destruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAHFy.png)

[Tabs Destroyed, leaving behind it's empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvV5n.png)

[How it originally looked before adding tabs. This is my desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3k1J.png)

Here's my Fragment that created the tabs.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.reddit_search_pager);
    mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

    setViewPager();
    setTabs();
}


public void setTabs() {
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String tabTitle = "";
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tabTitle = TAB_TITLE_SUBREDDITS;
                break;
            case 1:
                tabTitle = TAB_TITLE_POSTS;
                break;
            case 2:
                tabTitle = TAB_TITLE_USERS;
                break;
        }
        mActionBar.addTab(
                mActionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(tabTitle)
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
}
```

Here's my primary MainActivity pre-existing modification's to the toolbar.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NetworkingUtils myClass = new NetworkingUtils(this);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_menu);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I am working with `ListViews` I usually use adapters. With adapters you have to call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChaged()` every time you make a new change on your list so the list can update normally. Maybe that is what is happening to you so try to call some method like the one I showed above and it will maybe update and clear the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using another way to use tabs, the Tablayout as described in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ. I had to make my own Toolbar instead of the default theme one.

I have no idea why Android is suggesting a deprecated and buggy way to implement tabs on their official website instead of this. In fact, the TabLayout examples provided in the Youtube video are all 404 not found.